# Wpf Как получить путь Image в c#

Tags: c#, wpf, изображения

Сначала загружаю изображение в форму. Нужно отправить это изображение на сервер. Но не могу получить путь загруженного изображения.

```
  void ExecuteOpenFileDialog()
    {
        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            using (var stream = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.Open))
            {
                path = openFileDialog.FileName;
                MessageBox.Show(path);
                Image = BitmapFrame.Create(stream, BitmapCreateOptions.None, BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad);
                RaisePropertyChanged("Image");
                RaisePropertyChanged("path");
            }

        }
    }
          public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
```

Тут путь выдаёт нормально

```
fileName = ((BitmapFrame)img.Source).Decoder.ToString();
                    MessageBox.Show(fileName);
```

тут выдаёт вместо пути "image".
При создание объекта класса, где путь выдаёт нормально, выдаёт пустое сообщение. Как получить путь?

Картинка изменяется, а TextBox- нет

Comment: Почему вы не хотите сохранять path после открытия диалога  на уровне класса и передавать его, когда нужно?

Comment: Можно поподробнее?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Полностью рабочий пример, можно копировать к себе и запускать.

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
    xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow"
    SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
<Grid MinWidth="450" MinHeight="200">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Content="Open image"
            Click="ButtonBase_OnClick" />
    <Button Content="Show me the path"
            Grid.Column="1"
            Click="ButtonBase2_OnClick" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1"
               Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
               x:Name="imagePath" />
</Grid>
```

code behind

```
using System.Windows;
using Microsoft.Win32;

namespace WpfApp1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private string _filePath; // переменная уровня класса
    private void ButtonBase_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var d = new OpenFileDialog();
        if (d.ShowDialog().GetValueOrDefault(false))
        {
            _filePath = d.FileName; // сохраняем в переменную
        }
    }

    private void ButtonBase2_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        imagePath.Text = _filePath; // получаем данные из переменной. 
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Я реализую открытие диалога через другой класс, и через INotifyPropertyChanged вставляю картинку. Пытаюсь тоже самое сделать с Текстом, но он не меняется.

Comment: Покажите свой класс, гадать можно вечно